# Problem with plotting frames in Mathematica V 13.0.1

Tags: plotting, frame, version-13

Just upgraded to the latest version of Mathematica (13.0.1) and I encounter some weird behavior of plots. When plotting for example `Plot[0.0001 x, {x, 0, 1}]` I get a long and empty plot region.
Using `Plot[0.0001 x, {x, 0, 1},  Frame -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]` sometimes solves the problem but not in every case.
Did anyone experience it? Wondering what am I doing wrong.
[image: Example for the problem I encounter]
Thanks,
Ofek

Comment: Both examples consistently produce the same results for me. I am running MMA v13.0.1 in Windows 10, x86 machine.

Comment: Add the option `AspectRatio->4/5` to the plot command.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, adding aspect ratio doesn't change the results. And checking in another computer seems to work properly. Any idea how I can restore the default styling? (reinstalling the program didn't help)

Comment: Maybe your notebook is corrupted. Start with a new notebook and copy and execute the code from your question above.

Comment: @OfekPeretz: Is it possible that some change was made to a https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConfigurationFiles.html, which I think is maintained across updates?

Comment: What is the output of `ToBoxes@Plot[0.0001 x, {x, 0, 1}]`?

Comment: @Moo, I have restored the configuration file and the problem is now gone!!
Thanks you all so much for the help:)